# Getting wrong results for merge sort if i change index variable to zero and k=0 in merge function

Tags: c++, algorithm, mergesort

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define size 100
using namespace std;
void merge(int a[],int,int,int);
void merge_sort(int a[],int,int);
main(){
    int a[size],i,n;
    cout<<"Enter the no  of elements in the array: ";
    cin>>n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    merge_sort(a,0,n-1);
    cout<<"\nThe sorted array is: ";
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<a[i]<<"  ";
    }
}
void merge(int a[],int l,int m,int r){
    int i=l,j=m+1,index=1,temp[size],k;//HERE
    while((i<=m) && (j<=r)){
        if(a[i]<a[j]){
            temp[index]=a[i];
            i++;
        }
        else{
            temp[index]=a[j];
            j++;
        }
        index++;
    }
    if(i>m){
        while(j<=r){
            temp[index]=a[j];
            j++;
            index++;
        }
    }
    else{
        while(i<=m){
            temp[index]=a[i];
            i++;
            index++;
        }
    }
    for(k=1;k<index;k++){//HERE
        a[k]=temp[k];
    }
}

void merge_sort(int a[],int l,int r){
    int m;
    if(l<r){
        m=(l+r)/2;
        merge_sort(a,l,m);
        merge_sort(a,m+1,r);
        merge(a,l,m,r);
    }
}
```

for example if n=5 
 input: 5 8 7 1 4
output: 1 4 5 7 8
but if k=0 and index=0 
output is 1 1 4 4 8 
All i am doing is accessing temp array and array a which is argument of function  merge from index zero.
In case of taking index and k=1 why is array a not overflowing.
Any insight would be helpful.Thank You!

Comment: Your [`main` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) is invalid. And please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) Lastly, please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Both of the things you have stated are completely irrelevant to my question Secondly code was incorrect logically and had nothing to do with debugging..

Comment: Debugging is *the* way to find logical errors (most other errors are found by the compiler itself). If you step through the code in a debugger, line by line, while monitoring variables and their values you should have easily been able to find the problem. And while the other two points are not relevant to the problem itself, they *are* two important things you should consider. In fact, not declaring the `main` function correctly technically makes your program invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the way you copy values from `temp` to `a`. A correct code should looks like this (index should starts from 0):

```
for(k=0;k<index;k++){//HERE
    a[l+k]=temp[k];
}
```